# Google Maps - cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I hope somebody can help me with my Google Maps API code.

I have set up a map with multiple markers which works successfully, however I want to add on-click events to the markers so that an info window appears, this is where I hit the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true&callback=mapInitialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
function mapInitialize() {
    var options = {  
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    function codeAddress(markerValue, addressValue) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressValue}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                markerValue = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            }
        });
    }
    var marker1;
    codeAddress(marker1, '1 My Road, Somewhere, A1 1AA');
    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div class="infowindow"><strong><a href="http://mylink.com">Title</a></strong><br />Address details</div>'
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow1.open(map, marker1);  
    });
}
```

so I get the error 'Cannot read property '_*e3*' of undefined' when I include the addListener code.

I've read other posts on here of similar issues, but I have read all of the responses and even though they have the same problem none of the resolutions that worked for them have worked for me, or they are irrelevant to waht I have written.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

1. You're trying to modify the `marker1` variable passed into your `codeAddress` function from within the function by assigning to the argument name `markerValue`. JavaScript doesn't have pass-by-reference arguments, and so `marker1` is not in any way affected by your assigning a value to `markerValue`. So later when you try to do something with `marker1`, it still has its default value (`undefined`).
2. Google Maps' API is **asynchronous**. Your call to `geocoder.geocode` *starts* the process, but it completes later, long after `codeAddress` has returned.

You need to move your subsequent code *into* `codeAddress`, specifically into the completion callback from `geocode`.

*Something* like this (completely untested, the idea is to point you the right direction, not code a perfect solution for you):

```
function mapInitialize() {
    var options = {  
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), options);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    function codeAddress(addressValue) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressValue}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker, infowindow1;

                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<div class="infowindow"><strong><a href="http://mylink.com">Title</a></strong><br />Address details</div>'
                }); 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);  
                });
            }
        });
    }
    codeAddress('1 My Road, Somewhere, A1 1AA');
}
```