# Google maps api marker is not defined error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to place multiple markers on the map with the ability to click on them. That should then fire up a certain JS within my website and for that I'm using the following code:

```
function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(64.113598, -21.8569031),
          zoom: 12,
          scrollwheel: false,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

        function getAddress (address) {
          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
              });
            } else {
              return;
            }
          });
        }

        getAddress("some address here");

      }
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(8);
      });
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But this gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK` then the `marker` would not be getting initialized.  Could you please look into this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, but it is getting initialized, I do have a marker on my map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the `var marker` inside the function `getAddress`, and therefore this variable will only be available within this scope.  Please move the variable definition outside of `getAddress` like this:

```
var marker;

function initialize() {
    // ...

    function getAddress (address) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    getAddress("some address here");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Please step through using the Chrome debugger and check the value of `marker` right before your call to `addListener`.

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting `Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined` :) which, as far as I googled, is because the listener is being called within the initialize method (which isn't true in my case). /fixed it and now everything works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, and I also had to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979771/google-maps-cannot-read-property-e3-of-undefined